# xcode 3.1.1 create application for iphone(3,4,5)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My system (Mac OS X 10.5.8) only accepts xcode 3.1.1. is that this version allows me to develop applications for all iphone version (3,4,5) and ipad. whose functionality has what I need is (GPS, Map, Internet access, QRcode, SQLite) Thank you.

English is not my native language, sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but you won't be able to submit any application to Apple unless it is built with at least Xcode 5 (and probably Xcode 5.1 before long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David pointed out in the comments, you will not be able to submit any application to the App Store using that version of XCode.

Apple is probably pushing developers to use recent versions because it wants to avoid the hassle of having to maintain an indefinite number of legacy versions of its development tools. The same no doubt applies to OS X.

10.5.8 is extremely dated by today's standards and XCode has improved by leaps and bounds since 4.0, let alone 3.1.1. Fewer bugs, fewer crashes, a better UI, newer versions of LLVM, Clang, Objective-C itself, the iOS SDK... everything, practically. By sticking with OS X 10.5.8 and XCode 3.1.1, you are seriously impacting your ability to keep up with the latest in Apple technologies to say the least.